# I am new to Android app development, I am encountering problem. I have an APK File, but I would like to find in what API Level this file can run?

Tags: android, windows, macos, api

I have an APK File and I would like to find which platform in which API Level it will work. I have watched certain blog and youtube videos to install APK tool and then accessing it still did not work. I have tried the following steps using my Mac:

1. Downloaded the Mac wrapper script (Right click, Save Link As apktool)
2. Downloaded apktool-2 (find newest here)
3. Rename downloaded jar to apktool.jar
4. I have Moved both the files (apktool.jar & apktool) to /usr/local/bin (root needed)
5. I have also tried running using chmod command but it did not work, any help/ suggestion will be highly appreciated.

I would like to know how to find out in which API Level it will work.

I have an android phone Samsung s8 and current android version is Android v9.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Android Studio you can use the Analyze APK and you should find the AndroidManifest.xml in the package in there you should see this section

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="23"
    android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
```

in this example it is compiled for version 28 and requires a minimum if 23